# Hoffman singleton conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

So I am currently working on the Hoffman singleton conjecture. For those who do not know this conjecture, it is  asking whether there exists a 57-regular, girth 5 graph with $57^2+1$ vertices.

While working on it, I made some interesting observations:

> Observation 1: The Peterson graph and the Hoffman-Singleton graph is made up of vertex disjoint copies of C5s.

So is it possible to prove/disprove that a potential 57-regular girth 5 graph with $57^2+1$ vertices (if it exists) is also made up of vertex disjoint copies of the C5?

> Observation 2: The Peterson graph is made up of 2 vertex disjoint copies of the C5 and that the Hoffman-Singleton graph is made up of 5 vertex disjoint copies of the Peterson graph.

So can we prove/disprove that a potential 57-regular, girth 5 graph with $57^2+1=3250$ vertices (if it exists) is made up of $\frac{3250}{50}=65$ vertex disjoint copies of the Hoffman-Singleton graph?

Things that I have tried: The Cauchy Interlace theorem.

I am open to any ideas that you have tried, regardless of whether you succeeded or not.

Comment: Are you still thinking about this problem?  I made the same observations, and have some thoughts I'd be happy to chat about say over email and/or zoom.  I'm not sure if it's frowned upon for me to put my email here.

Comment: @KristapsJohnBalodis Apologies from the late reply. Have not been checking my StackExchange account for some time. Regarding this, this was for one of my undergraduate research projects. I've since submitted my report on it. But I wouldn't mind discussing with you my thoughts on it. You may email me at yongann.tan@gmail.com and we can figure something out from there.

Answer (score 3):

You might do a search on "Moore graphs".  There are various papers on the ArXiv discussing these graphs, see for example: [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.09577)

Comment: Thanks for bringing to my attention this paper (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion from the other answer is great. I wanted to add that it is not even known whether the Moore graph of degree 57 must contain a single copy of a Petersen graph, let alone a decomposition into disjoint Hoffman-Singleton graphs!

This is mentioned at the end of the first section of

> Godsil, C. D., Problems in Algebraic Combinatorics, Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, Vol. 2.

For something more recent see Kristína Kováčiková's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05353).

Comment: Thanks for bringing to my attention this paper. I will take a look at it. (+1)